# How can I programatically remove a UWP toast notification that was launched while in lock screen?

Tags: c#, uwp, notifications, toast

I'm launching a toast notification either from the background or in the foreground. When the notification was launched while the app is in the foreground, I can hide the notification using:

```
_ToastNotifier.Hide(notification);
```

But when the notification was launched from the background, it doesn't hide the notification from the screen and it keeps ringing the alert. I wish I can hide the notification when app is activated.

Also, removing using `ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove(tag);` didn't work for me.

To see it fail, do the following:

1. Run the app.
2. Make the tablet sleep(start menu>power>sleep or use the sleep button in the tablet).
3. Wake the tablet.
4. While in the lock screen, send a notification from a different device/server to the app.
5. You will hear the notification sound.
6. Open the app from the taskbar, don't activate the notification. This is the part where I want to hide the notification, the app is opened and I don't need the notification in the lower right side of the screen. The notification will not go away until you tap on it, which is very inconvenient.

Update: 
It doesn't matter if it's in the background or foreground. As long as the notification was received while in lock screen". Please see the steps.

Note that this Toast notofication has a looping audio and scenario="incomingCall".

Comment: Could you share a simple sample that could reproduce this issue with your steps?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the notification, simply call

```
ToastNotificationManager.History.Remove("tagOfNotification");
```

You'll have to specify a `Tag` (and optionally a `Group`) on your notification so that you can identify it and remove it.

```
var toast = new ToastNotification(xml);
toast.Tag = "tag1";

// Send the toast
```

Comment: How would you specify a a group. Removing from history using the tag didn't work for me. I'll update the question for more steps.

Comment: I figured out how to specify a group, I set it in the ToastNotification.Group before showing it. But ToastNotificationManager.History.RemoveGroup("mygroupid") still didn't work for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Share a repro project somewhere? Seems like we'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: How can I set the tag when I send notification via Azure Notification Hub?